# jreddit returning unexpected results

Tags: java, api, reddit, jreddit

Thanks a lot ! 
I got in working ,

The only problem I found is that when getting the comment id for the specific
 submission it returns broken up comments ,

E.g

```
Reddit reddit = new Reddit("USER","PASSWORD");
List<Submission> submissions =  reddit.getSubmission(1); //returns 1 submission

    for (Submission sub : submissions) {
     System.out.println("BEGINNING OF SUBMISSION \n"+sub);
     System.out.println(reddit.getCommentsForSubmission(sub.getIdentifier()));  //prints out
     System.out.println("END OF SUBMISSION \n");
    }
```

This code will print only the first comment which look like this ..

BEGINNING OF SUBMISSION
Submission(t3_31qc98)

[image]

END RUN

getCommentsForSubmission looks like this…

```
public List<Comment> getCommentsForSubmission(String subId){

    Comments coms = new Comments(getRestClient(), getUser());
    List<Comment> commentsSubmission = coms.ofSubmission(subId, null, 0, 8, 20, CommentSort.TOP);
    return commentsSubmission;
}
```

Why doesn't Jreddit print out the whole comment?

Answer (score 1):

`jReddit/src/main/java/com/github/jreddit/entity/Comment.java` class has the folowing `toString()`

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Comment(" + identifier + ")<" + ((body.length() > 10) ? body.substring(0, 10) : body) + ">";
}
```

You could potentially make a call to get the full comment:

```
comment.getBody();
```

The thing is that you are calling `System.out.println()` which would call automatically the `toString()` of the current object being called inside the method.